# Unable to serve static files correctly in Django app

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-staticfiles

I have installed in googlecloud VM (Ubuntu 16.04) a django application (1.8.19) with a static IP but when I access the page I am not able to load correctly all the static files (css, jquery etc.).
Although I have set the correct files paths in my apache conf file, the URLs fail to include the "static" part.
So instead of being like this:

```
http://myip/**static**/lib/css/assets.min.css
```

They are like this:

http://myip/lib/css/assets.min.css

Thus everything fails to get rendered correctly and I get the following errors in the webdeveloper:

[image]

I believe the issue must be somewhere in the settings.py file but I am not sure where as I clearly define the path to the static folder there as:

```
  MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/geonode/uploaded'
  STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/geonode/static/'


  TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/etc/geonode/templates',
    os.path.join(GEONODE_ROOT, 'templates'),
  )
  # Additional directories which hold static files
  STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    '/etc/geonode/media',
    os.path.join(GEONODE_ROOT, 'static'),
  ]
```

**EDIT**

This is my apache conf file in the sites-enabled folder:

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess geonode user=www-data threads=15 processes=2
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    LimitRequestFieldSize 32760
    LimitRequestLine 32760
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    WSGIProcessGroup geonode
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/geonode/wsgi/geonode.wsgi
    <Directory "/var/www/geonode/">
       Order allow,deny
       Options -Indexes
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static/ /var/www/geonode/static/
    Alias /uploaded/ /var/www/geonode/uploaded/
    Alias /robots.txt /var/www/geonode/robots.txt
    <Directory "/var/www/geonode/uploaded/documents/">
       Order allow,deny
       Deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/geonode/uploaded/layers/">
       Order allow,deny
       Deny from all
    </Directory>

 <Directory "/var/www/geonode/static_root/">
        Order allow,deny
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
        IndexOptions FancyIndexing
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/geonode/uploaded/thumbs/">
        Order allow,deny
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
        IndexOptions FancyIndexing
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/geonode/uploaded/avatars/">
        Order allow,deny
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
        IndexOptions FancyIndexing
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/geonode/uploaded/people_group/">
        Order allow,deny
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
        IndexOptions FancyIndexing
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/geonode/uploaded/group/">
        Order allow,deny
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
        IndexOptions FancyIndexing
    </Directory>

<Proxy *>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
    ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT II**

The STATIC_URL in my local_settings.py:

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

The template of base.html:

{% load i18n avatar_tags %}
{% load account socialaccount %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta Http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
    <meta Http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">
    <meta Http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
    <meta Http-Equiv="Pragma-directive: no-cache">
    <meta Http-Equiv="Cache-directive: no-cache">

    <title>{% block title %}{{ SITE_NAME }}{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block head %}
      {% if DEBUG_STATIC %}
          <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/css/jquery.dataTables.css?v={{ VERSION }}" rel="stylesheet" />
          <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/css/select2.css?v={{ VERSION }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
          <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/css/bootstrap.min.css?v={{ VERSION }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
          <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/css/jquery-ui.css?v={{ VERSION }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
      {% else %}
        <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/css/assets.min.css?v={{ VERSION }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
      {% endif %}

      <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}geonode/css/ext-compatibility.css?v={{ VERSION }}" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}geonode/css/ux-all.css?v={{ VERSION }}" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}geonode/css/base.css?v={{ VERSION }}" rel="stylesheet" />
      <style type="text/css">[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;}</style>
{% block extra_head %}
      {% endblock %}
    {% endblock %}
    <!--[if IE]>
      <script src="https://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
      <style>
        #ieflag{
            display: block !important;
            height: 150px;
            text-align: center;
        }
      </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="/catalogue/opensearch" title="GeoNode Search"/>
  </head>

  <body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}">
    <!-- Navbar -->
    {% block header %}
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <i class="fa fa-navicon fa-lg"></i>
</button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url "home" %}">GeoNode</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav toolbar">
                {% block tabs %}
                <li id="nav_layers">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{% trans "Data" %}<i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-lg"></i></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="{% url "layer_browse" %}?limit={{ CLIENT_RESULTS_LIMIT }}">{% trans "Layers" %}</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url "document_browse" %}?limit={{ CLIENT_RESULTS_LIMIT }}">{% trans "Documents" %}</a></li>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li><a href="{% url "services" %}?limit={{ CLIENT_RESULTS_LIMIT }}">{% trans "Remote Services" %}</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="{% url "layer_upload" %}">Upload Layer</a></li>
                {% if 'geonode.contrib.createlayer' in INSTALLED_APPS %}
                  <li><a href="{% url "layer_create" %}">{% trans "Create Layer" %}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
                <li><a href="{% url "document_upload" %}">Upload Document</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url "register_service" %}">{% trans "Add Remote Service" %}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
              </ul>
            </li>
                <li id="nav_maps">
              {% if user.is_authenticated %}
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{% trans "Maps" %}<i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-lg"></i></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="{% url "maps_browse" %}?limit={{ CLIENT_RESULTS_LIMIT }}">{% trans "Explore Maps" %}</a></li>
                <li> <a href="{% url "new_map" %}">{% trans "Create Map" %}</a></li>
              </ul>
              {% else %}
              <a href="{% url "maps_browse" %}?limit={{ CLIENT_RESULTS_LIMIT }}">{% trans "Maps" %}</a>
              {% endif %}
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{% trans "About" %}<i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-lg"></i></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="{% url "profile_browse" %}">{% trans "People" %}</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url "group_list" %}">{% trans "Groups" %}</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url "group_category_list" %}">{% trans "Group Categories" %}</a></li>
                {% if perms.announcements.can_manage %}
                <li><a href="{% url "announcements_list" %}">{% trans "Announcements" %}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="{% url "geonode.invitations:geonode-send-invite" %}">{% trans "Invite Users" %}</a></li>
                {% if user.is_superuser %}
                <li><a href="/admin/people/profile/add/">{% trans "Add User" %}</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url "group_create" %}">{% trans "Create Group" %}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
              </ul>
            </li>

            {% block extra_tab %}
            {% endblock %}
            {% endblock %}
          </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li>
              <div class="search">
                <form id="search" action="{% url "search" %}" >
                  <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                  {% if HAYSTACK_SEARCH %}
                  <input id="search_input" type="text" placeholder="Search" name="q">
                  {% else %}
                  <input id="search_input" type="text" placeholder="Search" name="title__icontains">
                  {% endif %}
                </form>
              </div>
                </li>
            {% if not user.is_authenticated and ACCOUNT_OPEN_SIGNUP %}
            <li><a href="{% url "account_signup" %}">{% trans "Register" %}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle avatar" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                {% autoescape off %}{% avatar user 42 %}{% endautoescape %}
                {% with full_name=user.first_name|add:' '|add:user.last_name %}
                  {% if full_name.strip %}
                    {{ full_name | truncatechars:20 }}
                  {% else %}
                    {{ user.username | truncatechars:20 }}
                  {% endif %}
                {% endwith %}
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-lg"></i>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="{{ user.get_absolute_url }}">{% trans "Profile" %}</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url "recent-activity" %}">{% trans "Recent Activity" %}</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url "messages_inbox" %}">{% trans "Inbox" %}</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="{% url "admin:index" %}">Admin</a></li>
                {% if 'geonode.geoserver' in INSTALLED_APPS %}
 <li><a href="{% url "proxy" %}?url={{ GEOSERVER_LOCAL_URL }}web">GeoServer</a></li>
                {% endif %}
                {% if user.is_superuser and USE_MONITORING %}
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="{% url "monitoring:index" %}">{% trans "Monitoring" %}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="{% url "help" %}">{% trans "Help" %}</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="/account/logout/">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
                      {% else %}
                      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#SigninModal" role="button" >{% trans "Sign in" %} </a></li>
              {% endif %}
            </ul>
          </div> <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </nav>
      {% endblock header %}
      <!-- End of Navbar -->

    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert" id="ieflag" style="display:none">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h1>You are using an outdated browser that is not supported by GeoNode.</h1>
      <p>Please use a <strong>modern browser</strong> like Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome or Safari.</p>
    </div>

  <div id="wrap">
    {% block middle %}
    <div class="container">
      {% include "_status_message.html" %}
      {% include "_announcements.html" %}
 {% include "_messages.html" %}
      {% block body_outer %}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        {% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
    {% endblock middle %}
  </div>

  {% block monitoring %}
  {% endblock %}

  {% block footer %}
  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>Data</li>
            <li><a href="{% url "layer_browse" %}?limit={{ CLIENT_RESULTS_LIMIT }}">{% trans "Layers" %}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url "document_browse" %}?limit={{ CLIENT_RESULTS_LIMIT }}">{% trans "Documents" %}</a></li>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a href="{% url "services" %}?limit={{ CLIENT_RESULTS_LIMIT }}">{% trans "Remote Services" %}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url "layer_upload" %}">Upload Layer</a></li>
            {% if 'geonode.contrib.createlayer' in INSTALLED_APPS %}
              <li><a href="{% url "layer_create" %}">{% trans "Create Layer" %}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            <li><a href="{% url "document_upload" %}">Upload Document</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url "register_service" %}">{% trans "Add Remote Service" %}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
</ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>Maps</li>
            <li><a href="{% url "maps_browse" %}?limit={{ CLIENT_RESULTS_LIMIT }}">{% trans "Explore Maps" %}</a></li>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li> <a href="{% url "new_map" %}">{% trans "Create Map" %}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>About</li>
            <li><a href="{% url "profile_browse" %}">{% trans "People" %}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url "group_list" %}">{% trans "Groups" %}</a></li>
            {% if perms.announcements.can_manage %}
            <li><a href="{% url "announcements_list" %}">{% trans "Announcements" %}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            <li><a href="{% url "geonode.invitations:geonode-send-invite" %}">{% trans "Invite Users" %}</a></li>
            {% if user.is_superuser %}
            <li><a href="/admin/people/profile/add/">{% trans "Add User" %}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url "group_create" %}">{% trans "Create Group" %}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>{% trans "Powered by" %} <a href="http://geonode.org">{% trans "GeoNode" %}</a> <em>{% trans "version" %} {{ VERSION }}</em></li>
            <li><a href="{% url "developer" %}">{% trans "Developers" %}</a> | <a href="{% url "about" %}">{% trans "About" %}</a><li>
          </ul>
          <label class="hidden">{% trans "Language" %}</label>
          {% if csrf_token != "NOTPROVIDED" %}
          {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE %}
          <form class="form-inline" action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
            <select class="col-md-6 pull-right" name="language" onchange="javascript:form.submit()">
              {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
              <option value="{{ lang.0 }}" {% ifequal LANGUAGE_CODE lang.0 %} selected="selected"{% endifequal %}>
                {{ lang.1 }}
 </option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
          </form>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  {% endblock footer %}


    <!-- Modal must stay outside the navbar -->
    {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
    <div class="modal fade" id="SigninModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{% trans "Sign in" %}</h4>
          </div>
          <form class="form-signin" role="form" action="{% url "account_login" %}?next={{ request.path }}" method="post">
            <div class="modal-body">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {% get_providers as socialaccount_providers %}
              {% if socialaccount_providers %}
                  {% include "socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html" with process="login" %}
                  {% include "socialaccount/snippets/login_extra.html" %}
                <hr>
              {% endif %}
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id_username" class="sr-only">{% trans "Username" %}:</label>
                <input id="id_username" class="form-control" name="login" placeholder="{% trans "Username" %}" type="text" />
              </div>
 <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id_password" class="sr-only">{% trans "Password" %}:</label>
                <input id="id_password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="{% trans "Password" %}" type="password" />
              </div>
              <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" /> {% trans "Remember Me" %}
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">{% trans "Sign in" %}</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <!-- End of Modal -->

    {% if DEBUG_STATIC %}
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/js/jquery.min.js?v={{ VERSION }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/js/jquery.dataTables.js?v={{ VERSION }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/js/jquery.timeago.js?v={{ VERSION }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/js/jquery.ajaxprogress.js?v={{ VERSION }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/js/jquery.ajaxQueue.js?v={{ VERSION }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/js/jquery-ui.custom.js?v={{ VERSION }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/js/jquery.raty.js?v={{ VERSION }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/js/bootstrap.min.js?v={{ VERSION }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/js/moment-with-locales.min.js?v={{ VERSION }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js?v={{ VERSION }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/js/json2.js?v={{ VERSION }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/js/select2.js?v={{ VERSION }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/js/waypoints.js?v={{ VERSION }}"></script>
    {% else %}
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}lib/js/assets.min.js?v={{ VERSION }}"></script>
    {% endif %}
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}geonode/js/utils/utils.js?v={{ VERSION }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}geonode/js/base/base.js?v={{ VERSION }}"></script>
    {% include 'autocomplete_light/static.html' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url "javascript-catalog" %}"></script>
    {% block extra_script %}{% endblock extra_script %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var autocomplete = $('#search_input').yourlabsAutocomplete({
            url: '{% url "autocomplete_light_autocomplete" "ResourceBaseAutocomplete" %}',
            choiceSelector: 'span',
            hideAfter: 200,
            minimumCharacters: 1,
            placeholder: '{% trans 'Type your search here ...' %}',
            appendAutocomplete: $('#search_input'),
            autoHilightFirst: false
        });
        $('#search_input').bind('selectChoice', function(e, choice, autocomplete) {
            if(choice[0].children[0] == undefined) {
                $('#search_input').val($(choice[0]).text());
                $('#search').submit();
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        // Workaround to fix the autocomplete box positions
        yourlabs.Autocomplete.prototype.fixPosition = function(html) {
            this.input.parents().filter(function() {
                return $(this).css('overflow') === 'hidden';
            }).first().css('overflow', 'visible');
            if(this.input.attr('name') !== 'resource-keywords'){
              this.box.insertAfter(this.input).css({top: 28, left: 0});
            }else{
              var pos = $.extend({}, this.input.position(), {
                height: this.input.outerHeight()
              });
              this.box.insertAfter(this.input).css({top: pos.top + pos.height, left: pos.left});
            }
        };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url "lang" %}"></script>
<div class="modal fade" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="_resource_uploading" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h1>Uploading...</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="progress">
                      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%">
                        Upload in progress...
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="_thumbnail_processing" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h1>Processing...</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="progress">
                      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%">
                        Updating Thumbnail...
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="_thumbnail_feedbacks" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Message box</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You claim you have set the paths correctly in your Apache config, but you have not shown that file.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I just added it. Thanks.

Comment: You also need to show the STATIC_URL setting and the template where you are linking to these assets.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I have added the template of index.html. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Apparently not. You are trying to load those assets in a template somewhere, but you say the URL is coming out wrong. So, *where* is the template that is loading them, and how are you producing that URL there?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I see what you mean. I have replaced the above template with the one where all these assets are first loaded. It is my base.html templates which gets "extended" to the other templates later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172812/discussion-between-user1919-and-daniel-roseman).

Comment: OK, now we can see that you're using STATIC_URL as a template variable. What have you done to define this? Did you enable the `static` context processor?

Comment: In my settings.py file I have defined the STATIC_URL variable. What else should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't done anything to make the STATIC_URL variable available in the template, so it is being evaluated to an empty string.

There are various ways of doing this but perhaps the simplest would be to add [`django.template.context_processors.static`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-static) to the `context_processors` list in your TEMPLATES setting.

Or you could call `{% get_static_prefix as STATIC_URL %}` at the top of your template.

Alternatively, don't use `STATIC_URL` at all but the `{% static %}` template tag:

```
<link href="{% static "lib/css/jquery.dataTables.css" %}?v={{ VERSION }}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Thanks. But still I have issues loading the page. I tried to use both ways but none works. Kindly check the chat

Comment: Moreover even if I hardcode in the URL the path, its still not appearing in the webdeveloper tool. Its like its loading these files from somewhere else..

Comment: So I see now there is another html file called index500.html. This is what is loaded if things break. Hardcoding the path to the static file there loads the files correctly. But the question is why the STATIC_URL variable is not loaded correctly at the first place.

Comment: Thanks mate. After all doing your second proposal made everything work. STATIC_URL messes with things when in production as described here: http://staticfiles.productiondjango.com/blog/stop-using-static-url-in-templates/

Answer (score 0):

If you think everything is true, add below code in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and then add below codes in urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_ROOT, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: This is not good practice for production. And it still doesn't work.